Git not authorized
on push through katalon studio to git repository gives git command as not authorized
I like to commit and push to git repository of my project from katalon studio but gives git command as Not authorized even after giving the proper credentials

You aren't giving us any details -- we don't know which protocol you're using to transport git over, we don't know if you've done any debugging specific to that protocol, we don't know what kind of credentials you're providing, etc; this question isn't answerable without much more information.

(if you're tunneling over ssh, then the place to start is to try to authenticate to the same service just with ssh, without git on top; running in verbose mode will give you information on which keys the client as presented, which keys if any the server rejected, etc)
